# Springboot AWS Cloud S3 resource loading

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-boot

I am building a web app with spring boot and trying to load css and some images from aws s3 bucket into my webapp's resources folder. Have tried to look some examples and tutorials with out any luck so far.

Would appreciate if someone can point me to the right example.

Thanks

Comment: What is even your question?

Comment: My question is to figure out a way to download the css and images on start of a server to local resource folder from aws s3 bucket.

Comment: Wouldn't this belong on like Server Fault?

Comment: I am not sure what is serve fault. I am using spring boot with tomcat and when I run the project using java -jar myproject.jar. What I am trying to do is connect to aws s3 bucket and download the client specific css and images to myproject local resources folder, so that my application can load the right css and images

Comment: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to attempt to download the resources to your webapp's resources folder. What you really want is to use S3 as your resources storage and **link** to the S3 resources.

An example of this is already available at: https://github.com/kbastani/spring-boot-starter-amazon-s3

Comment: Thanks.. Yes I found that's better way to do instead of downloading them...

Comment: If this answer helped you out, please accept and upvote it.

Comment: I am also not sure why it's on hold, I believe question is very straight forward but may be due to terminology it's not clear... Just as an example here is the link to some docs I referred... http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_downloading_files